# For $z\in\mathbb{C}$, prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}n$Log$(1+z/n) = z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Here Log is the principal complex logarithm, Log$z = \log|z| + i$Arg$z$.

I have tried multiple approaches none of which look even remotely promising. I know that Log is discontinuous along the negative real axis and this was a cause of some minor problems.

As a follow up I'm supposed to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+z/n)^n = e^z$ which I have done assuming the result in the title.

Can someone give me hints or an outline of what I can try?

Comment: Is there a missing power of $n$ in your title?

Comment: @nobody oops, yes, its suppose to be $n$Log$(1+z/n)$

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series for $\log$ about the point $1$?

Comment: Yes, $\log(x+1) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots,$

Comment: Then for $n$ large enough note that the taylor series is convergent at $z/n$. Try plugging in the taylor series and see what you get.

Comment: Is this using the real result for Taylor series or the complex one? I have not yet seen the complex result

Comment: I meant the complex one. Sorry for the confusion. Can you give us an idea of the kind of thing you have seen?

Comment: Cauchy Riemann equations, and then we defined $e$ and Log

Comment: Do you know that your Log function is analytic?

Comment: Except on the negative real axis right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$\text{Log}\left(1+\frac{z}n\right) = \log\left(\left|1+\frac{z}n\right|\right) + i\,\text{Arg}\left(1+\frac{z}n\right)$$

Now, let $z=a+bi$.
Then

$$\text{Arg}\left(1+\frac{z}n\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{\frac{b}n}{1+\frac{a}n}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{b}{n+a}\right)$$

From real analysis we know that

$$\arctan(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\,x^{2k+1}=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5-\dots$$

Hence,

\begin{align}
n\cdot\arctan\left(\frac{b}{n+a}\right)
&= n\,\frac{b}{n+a} - \frac{n}3\,\left(\frac{b}{n+a}\right)^3 + \frac{n}5\,\left(\frac{b}{n+a}\right)^5 - \dots\\
&\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\,\,b,
\end{align}

which shows that $\Im(z)=\Im\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,\text{Log}\left(1+\frac{z}n\right)\right)$.

For the real part, observe that

\begin{align}
\left|1+\frac{z}n\right|
&= \sqrt{{\left(1+\frac{a}n\right)}^2+{\left(\frac{b}n\right)}^2}\\
&= \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{n^2}\right)}
\end{align}

Hence, $\log\left(\left|1+\frac{z}n\right|\right) = \frac12\,\log\left(1+\left(\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{n^2}\right)\right)$.
We know from real analysis that for $|x|<1$

$$\log(1+x) = \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\,x^k=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\dots$$

Since $\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{n^2} \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, we have that for $n$ large enough:

\begin{align}n\cdot \log\left(\left|1+\frac{z}n\right|\right)
&=\frac{1}2\,\left[n\,{\left(\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{n^2}\right)}
-\frac{n}2\,{\left(\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{n^2}\right)}^2
+\frac{n}3\,\,{\left(\frac{2a}{n}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{n^2}\right)}^3
-\dots\right]\\
&\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\,\,\frac12\,[2a]=a.
\end{align}

This shows that $\Re(z)=\Re\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,\text{Log}\left(1+\frac{z}n\right)\right)$
and completes the proof. $\square$

Comment: Why can you express $\text{Arg}$ in terms of $\arctan$ in that way, should there not be multiple cases to consider?

Comment: Well, how do you define $\text{Arg}$?

Comment: Principal Argument, which is between $(-\pi,\pi]$. If you write $\text{Arg}(x+iy) = \arctan(y/x)$, then the points $1+i$ and $-1-i$ have the same argument despite been in different quadrants.

Comment: For $x>0$, it is true that $\text{Arg}(x+iy) = \arctan(y/x)$. For large $n$, we have that $\Re(1+\frac{z}n)>0$. It follows that for large $n$ we indeed have $\text{Arg}\left(1+\frac{z}n\right) = \arctan\big(\Im(z)/\Re(z)\big)$.